# SQL Server 2000 connection string converted to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, connection-string

I have a SQL Server 2000 connection string that I need to work with SQL Server 2008. I am using a DSN and it works just fine, but when I try to connect from the web page, the page never loads and I have to restart my IIS to get the web page to load again.

this is my SQL Server 2000 string:

```
MM_RFI_Datasource_STRING = "DSN=RFI_Datasource"
```

this is my SQL Server 2008 string:

```
MM_RFI_Datasource_STRING = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;DSN=RFI_Datasource;"
```

I have also tried: `MM_RFI_Datasource_STRING = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Data Source=servername/instance; Initial Catalog=RFI;Integrated Security=True";"`

I actually had it working once, but my hard drive was mistakenly erased and now I can't seem to get it to work again.

Any help would be appreciated. I am neither a web master or SQL expert so I am really winging it  here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the vast repository of connection strings here:  http://www.connectionstrings.com

You don't say how you want to connect to SQL Server - what programming language / system you're using.

But I would recommend you use ADO.NET connection strings is ever possible.

```
Server=servername/instance;database=RFI;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

would be a sample of such an ADO.NET connection string. Tweak it as needed, add more information if required etc.

Comment: I have spent many hours looking at www.connectionstrings.com. As a matter of fact that site helped me to get it working the first time.. before I screwed it up.. which is why I do not understand why I can't get it to work now.  The script is using VBscript. This site was built by someone who is no longer around and I just have to figure it out. I am not a scripter, I do not know VB, JAVA or any .NET,  so I am trying to learn it as I go. The connection string is in a .asp file, does that help?

Comment: I think my connection to the database is working, at least in the Event Log, I see successfully logged in messages, but my page just does not load. if I open it just by clicking and "open with IE" I get the form I need.  I think  I should add an ASP tag or create a new query.

Comment: @AnnettaC: probably best to create a new question and supply as much ASP relevant information as possible